# Is there an easier-to-reach mapping for ESC in Vim?

Tags: vim

When using Vim (specifically, MacVim), I hit ESC about a thousand times a day. It's a bit far to reach for such an important key.

Has anybody mapped this to something more comfortable? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: I know that `Control + [` does the same thing, but that's not really easier for me.

Answer (score 2):

Caps Lock is a nice alternative but these are predefined:

- `CTRL-[` which is completely equivalent to `ESC` and
- `CTRL-C` which is in most cases<sup>*</sup> the same as `ESC`

also, a very common mapping is the `jj` (or even `<leader>j`) since the sequence 'jj' is extremely rare in typing.

There is a similar discussion on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/397229/349708)

<sup>*it will not expand abbreviations</sup>

Comment: Interesting. What are the cases where CTRL-C is different?

Comment: @Nathan: I'm only aware of expansions as a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could remap the Caps Lock key to an ESC key which is shown via the following superuser question. [Map CapsLock key to ESC in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/14628/map-capslock-key-to-esc-in-mac-os-x)